Error al usar dayjs con node.js
Estoy usando la librería dayjs con node.js, soy nuevo en esto hace un rato instale por primera vez node.js, los pasos para la instalación de dayjs en node.js es instalar dayjs con npm:
npm install dayjs

y después escribir este código en el script para poder usar la librería:
const dayjs = require('dayjs')
dayjs().format()

pero siempre que escribo este codigo me sale que require no esta declarado (ReferenceError: dayjs is not defined), como si la librería no estuviese conectada o algo así, tienen idea de que pueda ser, ya lo he intentado instalar con el link cdn y pasa exactamente lo mismo.
